# Custom Code to Merge cell vertically

Tags: c#

I have custome Code to create a Grid.But it's not a GridView

```
Grid dt=new Grid();
var row = dt.NewRow();
 int cellIdx = 0;
 row.Cells[0].Text = "Hello";
 dt.Rows.Add(row);
    row.Cells[1].Text=" ";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    if (row.Cells[1].Text == " ")
    {
        row.Cells.Remove(row.Cells[1]);  
    }
```

With this code i can merge two cell as horizontally .But how can i merge 2 cell vertically.

Answer (score 0):

If merging horizontally means you are merging Cells in the same row, then this implies that vertically merging would be merging cells on different rows.

So one simple way would be:

```
//check if one more row exists
if(dt.Rows.Count >= rowIndex+1)
{
    //get text of cell to be merged
    string mergeText = dt.Rows[rowIndex + 1].Cells[cellIndex].Text;
    //add Text to cell above
    dt.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cellIndex].Text += Sring.Format("; {0}", mergeText);
    //delete text
    dt.Rows[rowIndex + 1].Cells.Remove(dt.Rows[rowIndex + 1].Cells[cellIndex]);
}
```

Obviously, if you want to merge in the other direction you'd need to replace the `+` with a `-` and the if clause needs to be adapted as well.

Comment: how can i find cellindex.Like row=row-1

Comment: Look at your question `int cellIdx = 0;` This is the cellIIndex. I just used a different name.

Comment: Thnx Serv for reply !! it just put data to previous cell